# Best Practice to deal with Apply on Pandas when the Dataframe is empty

Tags: python, pandas, apply

A common pattern I follow in my code is creating a function which will be applied row-wise and return a single value. For example:

```
def apply_function(row):
   if row["A"] == "valueA":
      return "foo"
   elif row["B"] == "valueB":
      return "bar"
   else: 
      return "baz"

df["applied_column"] = df.apply(apply_function, axis=1)
```

This is fine as long as `df` is not empty. But if is, `.apply` returns instead a DataFrame and I get an exception, so I usually follow this boilerplate code:

```
if not df.empty:
    df["applied_column"] = df.apply(apply_function, axis=1)
else:
    df["applied_column"] = None
```

This works but I feel is not very elegant and not a good practice. Is it indeed the stardard way of dealing with this situation of Pandas, or there is better practices to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly [set `return_type` so Pandas does not infer anything from the return value of your `apply_function`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

E.g.

```
res = df.apply(apply_function, axis=1, result_type="reduce")
```

always returns a `Series`.